# Power BI Slicer not formatting properly

Tags: powerbi

In my report, my date dropdown slicer looks like this when the report first loads:

[image: Current Slicer]

I want it to display without all the extra time and timezone nonsense like it does when I manually select one of the boxes after the report loads:

[image: Desired Slicer]

Does anyone know why this happens or how to fix it?

---

**Edit:** Here's a minimal .pbix example: [Link to File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=55000558957596116454)

Comment: Haven't seen this before and can't really reproduce the scenario after a few tries. Would you mind share more details or a minimal .pbix file?

Comment: @FoxanNg Please see my edit for a .pbix file example.

Comment: This is really weird. What's the exact steps you created this? I can't really reproduce it and I tried a simple copy and paste of the visual and it simply reverts back to "30/9/2017".

Comment: OK I can reproduce it after a few random clicks..

Comment: I'd say this is a UI bug of Power BI

Comment: @FoxanNg Yeah, pretty sure it's a bug. Super annoying when trying to deploy official company reports though. Sometimes it happens; sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: You can submit the issue [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/idb-p/Issues) and hope that they'll  have it fixed in future release.

Comment: One suggestion though, I see you're choosing dropdown slicer rather than the ranged ones. If so, can you change the date data type to text to avoid the backend-randomly-messed-up date formatting?

Comment: @FoxanNg I've submitted the issue: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Date-Slicer-Formatting-Bug/idi-p/345231 The text idea is a good workaround suggestion. I'd probably create a separate text column for that as I'd still like to use the dates in my measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on the August 2018 version now, and it seems to me that this issue has been fixed.
At least I'm not able to reproduce it.

With a dataset like below, a `Line Chart` and a regular `Slicer`, I get this:

```
Date,Value
2017-01-12,1
2017-01-13,4
2017-01-14,2
2017-01-15,4
2017-01-16,2
2017-01-17,2
2017-01-18,2
2017-01-19,5
2017-01-20,5
2017-01-21,5
2017-01-22,5
2017-01-23,6
2017-01-24,3
2017-01-25,6
2017-01-26,6
2017-01-27,5
2017-01-28,8
2017-01-29,4
2017-01-30,2
```

[image]

The slicing details (the `All` part in `Date All`) can be turned off by setting `Filter Restatement` under `Slicer Header` to `Off`. Maybe that would have solved the issue?

[image]

[image]

Please note that I've ignored the date hierarchies in both the `Line Chart` and the `Slicer`:

[image]

Comment: I haven't run into this problem for a while now, so I'm guessing it has been fixed since I asked the question over 6 months ago.

Comment: I think you're right! And I think the Filter restatement feature is pretty new too.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, you might want to try creating a  new Column using the FORMAT function.

This is something I often do to provide a more human readable date for my slicer.

EG:

```
DisplayDate = Format([SomeDateField], "ddd d mmm yyyy" )
```

Once done - you will want to select the column - then SORT by your original date column.  Otherwise you may get some odd results ;)